# If/Then with RadioButton

Tags: vba, radio-button, if-statement, case

In my VBA code, I query a SQL table. I want to add an if/then statement so if one radio button is selected it pulls a certain value, and if the other radio button is selected, it pulls a different value. My if is radiobutton1, and my else is radiobutton2, although the else can just be to take the other value.

Here's the specific part of the code:

```
strSQL = strBeginSQL1(strRiskSegment, "Detail")
strSQL = strSQL & "a.field1, b.field1, "
strSQL = strSQL & "a.field2, b.field2, a.field3, b.field3,"
```

If my if/then is for field3 (the radio button will point to field4.)

How do I add the if/then statement in at this point? I thought it would be:

```
strSQL = strBeginSQL1(strRiskSegment, "Detail")
strSQL = strSQL & "a.field1, b.field1,"
strSQL = strSQL & "a.field2, b.field2, If radiobutton2.true then a.field4, b.field4, else a.field3, b.field3,"
strSQL = strSQL & "a.field5, b.field5,"
```

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be using stored procedures.

It would probably make your code a little cleaner to just build two different strSql & statements for example

```
strSQL = strBeginSQL1(strRiskSegment, "Detail")
strSQL = strSQL & "a.field1, b.field1,"
if (radiobutton2.value = true) then
strSQL = strSQL & "a.field4, b.field4"
else if (radiobutton3.value = true)
strSql = strSQL & "a.field3, b.field3"
endif
strSQL = strSQL & "a.field5, b.field5,"
```

but this is a terrible way and you should just pass these variables to a stored proc.

Comment: I tried this but I got:

run-time error '438';
Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Eh, just a syntax error. It's (radiobutton2.value = true) Thanks for the help!

Comment: no problem, just out of curiosity are stored procedures an option with this project?

Comment: Don't see why not. I'm not so familiar with them, that's all. Next week's training on exactly that topic should help, there will be a lot of updates to the project, so maybe in phase 2 we'll clean up the code a bit.